# Foreach in an array object in javascript I can't access the elements

Tags: javascript

This is my object array

```
[{ docNum: "7"
  docType: {code: "J", description: "Kons", lang: "I", category: "DELIVERY"}
  docYear: "0000"
  posNum: "000010"
},
{ docNum: "11"
  docType: {code: "J", description: "Kons", lang: "I", category: "DELIVERY"}
  docYear: "2145"
  posNum: "000020"
},
]
```

I need to access the DocNum property, I try this

```
array.forEach(element =>{
console.log("DocNum",element.docNum);
});
```

But in console I have this: "DocNum undefined"

Comment: Is that how your actual object looks? If so, you are missing commas between properties.

Comment: Start by logging each element to see what you are working with

Comment: There's error in ur array of object, separate each property with trailing commas

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

```js
let arr = [{
    docNum: "7",
    docType: {
      code: "J",
      description: "Kons",
      lang: "I",
      category: "DELIVERY"
    },
    docYear: "0000",
    posNum: "000010"
  },
  {
    docNum: "11",
    docType: {
      code: "J",
      description: "Kons",
      lang: "I",
      category: "DELIVERY"
    },
    docYear: "2145",
    posNum: "000020"
  }
]

arr.forEach(element => {
  console.log("DocNum", element.docNum);
});
```

You missed the commas after the properties

Comment: You sAd? I upvoted, I don't see a reason why the dude downvoted it.

Comment: Yes, the properties are divided by a comma but array.forEach(element => { console.log("Element",element); }); works but this doc.forEach(function(element) { let i = doc.indexOf(element); let docNum = element.docNum; let deliveryParams = new ParamsBuilder( "http...." ) .param(ParamsBuilder.UrlReplacements.NUM, docNum) .build(); } doesn't work

Comment: Your code works fine, until 'new ParamsBuilder'. But I cannot test this because it's an import of yours.

Answer (score 2):

your object is wrong, you need to add commas at properties

```
var array=[{ docNum: "7",
  docType: {code: "J", description: "Kons", lang: "I", category: "DELIVERY"},
  docYear: "0000",
  posNum: "000010"
},
{ docNum: "11",
  docType: {code: "J", description: "Kons", lang: "I", category: "DELIVERY"},
  docYear: "2145",
  posNum: "000020"
},
];

array.forEach(element =>{
console.log("DocNum",element.docNum);
});
```

Comment: Yes, the properties are divided by a comma but array.forEach(element => {
          console.log("Element",element);
        }); works but this doc.forEach(function(element) {
          let i = doc.indexOf(element);
          let docNum = element.docNum;
          let deliveryParams = new ParamsBuilder(
            "http...."
          )
            .param(ParamsBuilder.UrlReplacements.NUM, docNum)
            .build();
   } doesn't work